# Delete item from observed Object Array from within ForEach loop and update UI accordingly

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swiftui, observable

I am fetching posts from a database for an IOS App, in order to handle memory a bit better, I want to delete posts that I fetched and displayed at the top of the scrollview. So in other words I want to delete the first post fetched when a condition is true and update the UI accordingly. I can remove the first post from my array, however the ScrollView always shows the wrong post being deleted, it does not update the UI properly according to the array. Another question, do I have to change the indices of the remaining posts in the arrays?

```
struct HomeScreen: View {

@State var firstInitiation = false
@EnvironmentObject var homeScreenVmgr: ViewModelGetRequests
@State var  previousPostid = 0

var body: some View {
    
    ScrollView{
        LazyVStack{
            //Here we get new documents always when we appear on the last post
            ForEach(homeScreenVmgr.loadedPosts.indices, id:\.self){
                postIndex in let post = homeScreenVmgr.loadedPosts[postIndex]
                HomeViewAsync(experience: post)
                    .onAppear{
                        
                        if ((self.previousPostid < postIndex) && (homeScreenVmgr.loadedPosts.count >= 10)){
                            homeScreenVmgr.loadedPosts.removeFirst()
                            var count = 0
                            for post in homeScreenVmgr.loadedPosts{
                                post.id = count
                                count += 1
                            }
                        }
                        if postIndex == homeScreenVmgr.loadedPosts.count-1{
                            homeScreenVmgr.getPosts()
                        }
                        self.previousPostid = postIndex
                    }
            }
        }
        .background(Color.clear)
        .listRowInsets(.init())
        .border(Color.clear, width: 1)
        .padding(.top)
        
    }
    .onAppear(perform: {
        //This is the initial function to get the first 4 documents
        if firstInitiation == false{
            homeScreenVmgr.getPosts()
            firstInitiation = true
        }
    })
}
```

}

Comment: It's highly recommended to do all stuff to modify the data source in the view model. And as you iterate the indices rather than the items the `id` property is irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you! How does it work tho, does the for Each react to changes in the observable object like other views do? Like if I make a call to the view model to change the entries, does the ForEach loop change according to the array changes?

Comment: To answer your question, yes. When the EnvironmentObject changes, the view updates. From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentobject) *An environment object invalidates the current view whenever the observable object changes.*